# problemas con commits en visual studio code

Tags: c#, git, vscode, github, git-commit

tengo un problema que no se si es de visual studio code o de gitlens pero necesito una respuesta ajaj.
en el control de codigo fuente de mi proyecto en visual, sale como si no hubiera hecho ningun commit cuando si los hice y estan github. en la imagen se ven todos los commits que deberia hacer pero ya los hice!! igualmente cuando uso git bash en esa carpeta tambien aparece como si tuviera q hacer todos esos commits
no se por que paso eso ni como solucionarlo o q hacer. agradeceria la ayuda, gracias!

[image: control de codigo fuente en visual studio code]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora use git log para ver el historial de confirmaciones y sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: hola, si creo q no me explique bien. mi problema era q los commits aparecian en github pero no en vscode ni en git bash y me pedia q los hiciera de nuevo. lo que preguntaba era por que podia haber pasado eso y como solucionarlo. creo q ahora se entiende mejor? gracias!

Comment: La pregunta no es del todo clara pero necesitas recordar algunos conceptos. Esos no son *commits*, esos son cambios que están en el *staging area* (o *index*). Los cambios que formarán parte del próximo *commit* son los que se encuentran en *staging area*.

Comment: hola, gracias por los conceptos! se que no son commits y ese es el problema, deberian ser commits, no cambios porque no cambie nada en esos archivos. no se si me explico mejor? gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontre una solucion al problema que funciona mejor que solo clonar el repo

1. clonar el repo en otra carpeta
2. copiar la carpeta .git del repo nuevo
3. reemplazar la carpeta .git en el repo viejo

y con eso tendria que funcionar

les dejo el link de una persona que tuvo el mismo problema que yo por si quieren leer mas opciones

gracias a los que contestaron! :D

[solucion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012869/broken-branch-in-git-fatal-your-current-branch-appears-to-be-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Por [lo que me dijiste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/613267/problemas-con-commits-en-visual-studio-code/613309?noredirect=1#comment1081127_613309), esos no son commits. Son los archivos que se encuentran en el *staging area* o *index*.

Según el libro de git, [los archivos pueden estar en 3 estados](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F#_the_three_states) o mejor dicho, los archivos pueden estar en 3 ubicaciones (*working directory*, *staging area* o repositorio local)

El comando `git add` copia los archivos seleccionados al *working directory*. A los archivos que estén en esta ubicación se les dice *staged* y son los que van a formar parte del próximo commit.

Con el comando `git status` puedes ver una lista de esos archivos bajo el texto "*Changes to be committed*".

Answer (score -1):

la unica solucion q encontre fue volver a clonar el repositorio y copiar los cambios q tenia en mi proyecto anterior. pero todavia no se por que paso

Comment: Y si te vuelve a aparecer lo mismo clonarás de nuevo y perderás los cambios sin guardar? Yo creo que hay algo que no estás entendiendo. Cuando te vuelva a suceder comparte la captura de **Cambios staged** y lo que te aparece cuando usas el comando `git status`. Mientras tanto puedes darle una leída [al libro](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2).

Comment: hola, agregue la captura cuando uso el comando git status y otra usando git log, que segun el libro es para ver el historial de confirmaciones. gracias por el libro!

Comment: Y esos archivos también te aparecen en `staged`, en Visual Studio Code, cierto?

Comment: sii aparecen ahi

Comment: Siempre es mejor editar una respuesta que crear una nueva.